# How to make NVIDIA GeForce 680m default graphics card instead of Intel HD Graphics 4000? (Alienware M17 Laptop)

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

I believe that the question title describes it all... but I just bought 2 brand new 2560x1440 monitors and I need to make use of my NVIDIA GeForce 680m card instead of the Intel HD Graphics 4000 card. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

As long as your monitors are plugged into your GeForce Graphics card, it will be using that one.

Comment: on a laptop there's only one output, and you're using something like optimus to switch. It isn't like a desktop